# what's the definition of tensorflow hub imagenet classification module output classes

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

such as [inception_resnet_v2](https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/inception_resnet_v2/classification/1) module,in this page,it says there are 1001 classes see above ,but I can't find this definition of class indices
[1001 classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbeGz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/133 for a quick answer (and the request to document that more properly)